# Logstash with Google PubSub Input Plugin “Error: certificate verify failed”

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm struggling to make the Google PubSub Plugin work, I followed all the setup steps (creating a topic, creating a dedicated service account etc. pp.) My configuration looks like this:

```
input {
   google_pubsub {
       project_id => "secret"
       topic => "fw-services-logs"
       subscription => "fw-logstash-sub"
       json_key_file => "/usr/share/logstash/service_account_key.json"
   }
}

output { stdout { codec => rubydebug } }


# Works:
# input { stdin { } }
# output { stdout { codec => rubydebug } }
```

However when I build & run it, I get the following output:

```
Sending Logstash's logs to /usr/share/logstash/logs which is now configured via log4j2.properties
[2017-10-27T11:39:46,455][INFO ][logstash.modules.scaffold] Initializing module {:module_name=>"fb_apache", :directory=>"/usr/share/logstash/modules/fb_apache/configuration"}
[2017-10-27T11:39:46,462][INFO ][logstash.modules.scaffold] Initializing module {:module_name=>"netflow", :directory=>"/usr/share/logstash/modules/netflow/configuration"}
[2017-10-27T11:39:46,694][INFO ][logstash.modules.scaffold] Initializing module {:module_name=>"arcsight", :directory=>"/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/x-pack-5.6.3-java/modules/arcsight/configuration"}
[2017-10-27T11:39:46,714][INFO ][logstash.setting.writabledirectory] Creating directory {:setting=>"path.queue", :path=>"/usr/share/logstash/data/queue"}
[2017-10-27T11:39:46,720][INFO ][logstash.setting.writabledirectory] Creating directory {:setting=>"path.dead_letter_queue", :path=>"/usr/share/logstash/data/dead_letter_queue"}
[2017-10-27T11:39:46,795][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] No persistent UUID file found. Generating new UUID {:uuid=>"a144c8d2-12a9-4a15-a629-59910dda9295", :path=>"/usr/share/logstash/data/uuid"}
[2017-10-27T11:39:48,114][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Elasticsearch pool URLs updated {:changes=>{:removed=>[], :added=>[http://logstash_system:xxxxxx@elasticsearch:9200/]}}
[2017-10-27T11:39:48,118][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Running health check to see if an Elasticsearch connection is working {:healthcheck_url=>http://logstash_system:xxxxxx@elasticsearch:9200/, :path=>"/"}
[2017-10-27T11:39:48,343][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Attempted to resurrect connection to dead ES instance, but got an error. {:url=>"http://logstash_system:xxxxxx@elasticsearch:9200/", :error_type=>LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::HttpClient::Pool::HostUnreachableError, :error=>"Elasticsearch Unreachable: [http://logstash_system:xxxxxx@elasticsearch:9200/][Manticore::ResolutionFailure] elasticsearch: Name or service not known"}
[2017-10-27T11:39:48,345][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] New Elasticsearch output {:class=>"LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch", :hosts=>["http://elasticsearch:9200"]}
[2017-10-27T11:39:48,346][INFO ][logstash.pipeline        ] Starting pipeline {"id"=>".monitoring-logstash", "pipeline.workers"=>1, "pipeline.batch.size"=>2, "pipeline.batch.delay"=>5, "pipeline.max_inflight"=>2}
[2017-10-27T11:39:48,389][INFO ][logstash.licensechecker.licensereader] Elasticsearch pool URLs updated {:changes=>{:removed=>[], :added=>[http://logstash_system:xxxxxx@elasticsearch:9200/]}}
[2017-10-27T11:39:48,390][INFO ][logstash.licensechecker.licensereader] Running health check to see if an Elasticsearch connection is working {:healthcheck_url=>http://logstash_system:xxxxxx@elasticsearch:9200/, :path=>"/"}
[2017-10-27T11:39:48,404][WARN ][logstash.licensechecker.licensereader] Attempted to resurrect connection to dead ES instance, but got an error. {:url=>"http://logstash_system:xxxxxx@elasticsearch:9200/", :error_type=>LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::HttpClient::Pool::HostUnreachableError, :error=>"Elasticsearch Unreachable: [http://logstash_system:xxxxxx@elasticsearch:9200/][Manticore::ResolutionFailure] elasticsearch"}
[2017-10-27T11:39:48,435][WARN ][logstash.licensechecker.licensereader] Marking url as dead. Last error: [LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::HttpClient::Pool::HostUnreachableError] Elasticsearch Unreachable: [http://logstash_system:xxxxxx@elasticsearch:9200/][Manticore::ResolutionFailure] elasticsearch {:url=>http://logstash_system:xxxxxx@elasticsearch:9200/, :error_message=>"Elasticsearch Unreachable: [http://logstash_system:xxxxxx@elasticsearch:9200/][Manticore::ResolutionFailure] elasticsearch", :error_class=>"LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::HttpClient::Pool::HostUnreachableError"}
[2017-10-27T11:39:48,445][ERROR][logstash.licensechecker.licensemanager] Unable to retrieve license information from license server {:message=>"Elasticsearch Unreachable: [http://logstash_system:xxxxxx@elasticsearch:9200/][Manticore::ResolutionFailure] elasticsearch", :class=>"LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::HttpClient::Pool::HostUnreachableError"}
[2017-10-27T11:39:48,446][WARN ][logstash.licensechecker.xpackinfo] Nil response from License Server
[2017-10-27T11:39:48,486][INFO ][logstash.pipeline        ] Pipeline .monitoring-logstash started
[2017-10-27T11:39:48,536][INFO ][logstash.pipeline        ] Starting pipeline {"id"=>"main", "pipeline.workers"=>2, "pipeline.batch.size"=>125, "pipeline.batch.delay"=>5, "pipeline.max_inflight"=>250}
[2017-10-27T11:39:50,049][INFO ][logstash.inputs.googlepubsub] Client authorizataion with JSON key ready
[2017-10-27T11:39:50,051][INFO ][logstash.pipeline        ] Pipeline main started
[2017-10-27T11:39:50,235][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
[2017-10-27T11:39:50,875][ERROR][logstash.pipeline        ] A plugin had an unrecoverable error. Will restart this plugin.
  Plugin: <LogStash::Inputs::GooglePubSub project_id=>"secret", topic=>"fw-services-logs", subscription=>"fw-logstash-sub", json_key_file=>"/usr/share/logstash/service_account_key.json", id=>"23998ce4135823320ff87ea3bf3ca73094144ca9-1", enable_metric=>true, codec=><LogStash::Codecs::Plain id=>"plain_41007486-427e-4323-99fd-9375470f239e", enable_metric=>true, charset=>"UTF-8">, max_messages=>5>
  Error: certificate verify failed
```

When I run with debug logging level, I see that it crashes somewhere in Faraday:

```
[2017-10-27T12:42:01,538][ERROR][logstash.pipeline] A plugin had an unrecoverable error. Will restart this plugin.
  Plugin: <LogStash::...>
  Error: certificate verify failed
  Exception: Faraday::SSLError
  Stack: org
```

*Questions:*

- Any idea how I can fix the crashing of the plugin because of the certificate verify failed error?
- Are these warnings / info logs regarding ElasticSearch normal? AFAIK I don't need to use ES, right?

The docker file I use:

```
FROM docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash:5.6.3

ADD service_account_key.json /usr/share/logstash/service_account_key.json

# https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/docker.html
RUN rm -f /usr/share/logstash/pipeline/logstash.conf
ADD ./pipeline/ /usr/share/logstash/pipeline/

RUN logstash-plugin install logstash-input-google_pubsub
```

And I build and run it like:

```
docker build -t logstash -f logstash.docker --no-cache .
docker run -it logstash
```

Comment: First thing I would do is run LogStash with the debug level turned up to Debug, hopefully you'll be able to see where in the authentication process it's getting stuck https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/logging.html

Comment: Thanks, I actually tried that already (and forgot to updated my question). I get a `Exception: Faraday::SSLError`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explicitly setting the `SSL_CERT_FILE` fixed the issue.

```
# see https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client/issues/253
ENV SSL_CERT_FILE /usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/certs/cacert.pem
```

By default Logstash tries to log monitoring information to Elasticsearch.
If you, like in my case don't want that to happen you can disable it with:

```
ENV XPACK_MONITORING_ENABLED false
```

For debugging these kind of issues it's handy to set the Logstash logging level to `debug`:

```
ENV LOG_LEVEL debug
```